# Can an admin delete users from a firebase application?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

On my application users are provisioned and delete by the admin.  The documentation states that auth.removeUser requires an ID and password.  Of course the admin user doesn't know its users passwords.  Is there a way for the admin user to get permission to delete users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [Firebase Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) is a separate service built on top of [Firebase Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/authentication.html), intended to simplify authenticating users and generating Firebase Auth. Tokens for use in [Security Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html).

All that said, if you log in to Firebase Forge (at `https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com`) and select the `Auth` tab, you can add or remove email / password users under the `Email & Password` button.